# Do I still get credited for move and stand goals if my Apple Watched is locked while on my wrist?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app, fitness+

One thing I've been curious about and tried to check but haven't been able to fully confirm, is - if my Apple Watch is on my wrist but still locked (i.e. I just put it back on my wrist and have not put in my passcode):

- If I move around, will I get credited for that fitness activity?
  (i.e. Will the active calories, exercise and stand rings still go up)
  if I later remember to put in my passcode?
- Will the watch do heartrate and other readings and add that to Health when locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billie Hawkins has noted about the stand goals. I checked to see if the Apple Watch would track steps.

So here was my test:

- Take off Apple Watch (Series 3)
- Verify locked state
- Checked number of steps using   [Pedometer++](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pedometer/id712286167) on iPhone (current steps: 8367)
- Walk for 3 minutes around the house
- Checked number of steps on Pedometer++ (steps shown: 8367)
- Unlocked Apple Watch
- Noticed that Pedometer++ changed the number of steps to 8664 (which is about right for me walking 3 mins in the house)
- Verified number of steps on Pedometer++ Watch app (confirmed 8664 steps)

So, yes, the Apple Watch will track your steps if it is locked but will update after it has been unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious too. In my tests, while locked, the watch *didn't* do a step count as I walked to the mailbox (about 150 feet), but it *did* count towards my stand goal.